# How to extend only parts of a method

Tags: php, laravel

We're developing an application that has some standard functionality.
However we wish to extend these methods to be able to add code on parts on some methods in certain situations. In order to not have to "copy + paste" the code constantly we're looking for something along the lines of the following:

**Class a**

```
public function foo()
{
  $test = new testObj()
    ->setName('Fred Flintstone')
    ->setPhone('0000-123456')
    ->setEmail('fred@flintstone.com');

  // Here we would like to be able to add code from another class

  $test->save();
}
```

**Class b**

```
public function bar()
{
  $test->setAddress('Flintstonedrive 10');
}
```

When we call function bar() we would like that the whole function foo() is called and what's in bar() will be executed at the place marked in the foo() function.

This way we can do different sorts of mutations from separate classes as these will be customer specific changes but 90% of the code is the same for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really possible as you described, but you have two similar options

If B extends A, you can have a (virtual) function that A calls where you want it to happen, and call the Foo function on B.

If B is contained in A, you can have an Interface that any such B must implement and call that in Foo, then call the Foo function on A.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you've given, a simple callback might suffice (if you just want to let another object tinker with your test object):

```
public function foo(Callable $callback = null) {

    $test = new Test();

    ...

    if ($callback) {

        $callback($test);
    }

    ...
}
```

In context:

```
class Test {

    protected $name;
    protected $phone;
    protected $email;
    protected $address;

    public function setName(string $name) {

        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setPhone(string $phone) {
        
        $this->phone = $phone;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email) {
        
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setAddress(string $address) {
        
        $this->address = $address;
        return $this;
    }
}

class Foo {

    public function foo(Callable $callback = null) {

      $test = new Test();

      $test->setName('Fred Flintstone')
           ->setPhone('0000-123456')
           ->setEmail('fred@flintstone.com');

      if ($callback) {

        $callback($test);
      }
      
      var_dump($test);
    }
}

class Bar {

    public function bar() {

        $foo  = new Foo();
        
        $foo->foo(function (Test $test) {

            $test->setAddress('Cave 123');
        });
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();

$foo->foo(); // Gives test object without address
$bar->bar(); // Same object with address
```

See also [this PHPSandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/weathered-surf-leem-635t0) to run the code.